# How to properly pass variables across Azure Pipeline YAML deployment stages?

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to pass the variables across deployment jobs between 2 stages. In below example there are 3 stages: StageA, One and StageB. StageA has a job A1(simple job), Stage One has 2 jobs ( A- simple job and B1- deployment job).

So when I am trying to fetch the values of these 3 jobs in stageB deployment job B2, I am getting variable values only from Job A1 and job A(both simple jobs) but not from the deployment job B1.

I tried all combination with simple jobs and deployment jobs and found below

- Stage(simple job) -- stage(simple job) -- working
- Stage(deployment) -- stage(simple job) -- not working
- Stage(job) -- stage(deployment) -- working
- Stage(deployment) -- stage(deployment) -- not working

Thus from above what I understood is that when the variable is getting set at deployment job level it is not reflecting in next stage for both deployment and simple jobs.

where I am going wrong?

```
stages:
- stage: StageA
  jobs:
   - job: A1
     steps:
      - pwsh: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunStageB;isOutput=true]true"
        name: setvarStep
      - bash: echo $(System.JobName)
- stage: One
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVar;isOutput=true]this is a simple job"      
        name: ProduceVar
      - bash: echo $(ProduceVar.MyVar)
        name: echovar
  - deployment: B1
    environment: Development  
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVarTwo;isOutput=true]this is the second deployment variable value"
            name: setvarStepTwo
          - bash: echo $(setvarStepTwo.myOutputVarTwo)
            name: echovar1
- stage: StageB
  dependsOn: 
    - StageA
    - One

  variables:
    myOutputVar: $[stageDependencies.StageA.A1.outputs['setvarStep.RunStageB']]
    myOutputVar1: $[stageDependencies.One.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar']]
    myOutputVar2: $[stageDependencies.One.B1.outputs['setvarStepTwo.myOutputVarTwo']]
  jobs:
  - deployment: B2
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: envB
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - bash: echo $(myOutputVar)
          - bash: echo $(myOutputVar1)
          - bash: echo $(myOutputVar2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug the `stageDependencies` with adding this to the variables:

```
stage_stageDependencies: $[ convertToJson(stageDependencies) ]
```

And print it:

```
- script: "echo '$(stage_stageDependencies)'"
```

According to the output:

```
  "One": {
    "B1": {
      "outputs": {
        "B1.setvarStepTwo.myOutputVarTwo": "this is the second deployment variable value"
      },
      "identifier": null,
      "name": "B1",
      "attempt": 1,
      "startTime": null,
      "finishTime": null,
      "state": "NotStarted",
      "result": "Succeeded"
    },
```

You can see what is the correct syntax:

```
myOutputVar2: $[stageDependencies.One.B1.outputs['B1.setvarStepTwo.myOutputVarTwo']]
```

Result:

[image]